# Wordpress working only in directory named "wordpress"

Tags: hosting

I have this strange problem. Can't get wordpress running in any sub directory except domain.com/wordpress. Files are clean wordpress download and working on other hosting (tested).
Any recomendations?

edit: wordpress gives "white screen of death" when moved to other than domain.com/wordpress directory, except root (domain.com)

Comment: Is the path to your installation correct in the wp_options table?

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`

Comment: there is no database or .htaccess file yet. it is clean wordpress installation downloaded from wordpress.org and uploaded to server

Comment: Probably problem with .htaccess or the site url in the setting. Or check your domain where it is pointed.

Answer (score 0):

In `wp_options`, there are 2 values you need to change. The first is `site_url`, which is the first entry. The second one is `home`, which is entry 36 (page 2). These store the URL of your site, so if you wish to move it, you need to change these.

Comment: This is clean wordpress instalation. There is no db or .htaccess file yet. Thats why i find this problem odd. I believe it may be server misconfiguration, but maybe someone had similar problem. Wordpress instalation is launching in root (domain.com) or "wordpress" directory (domain.com/wordpress), but not working in others (domain.com/foo, domain.com/wp ...)

Comment: So in your `domain.com/foo` directory, it is another WordPress installation? It should be all means work fine. WP doesn't take over the URL structure of existing folders, so even if you had a `/foo` page on your `domain.com` installation, it should open up fine. Make sure the `index.php` file is inside `domain.com/foo`.

Comment: I have 1 wordpress instalation in my server. If i put wordpress in root (domain.com) it works, if i put wordpress (same files without editing) to domain.com/wordpress it works, but if i put them to any other folder, i get "white screen of death". I have been working with wordpress for more than 5 years, havent seen this before

Comment: Very bizarre. Is there any existing `.htaccess` file that you are moving with it? There could be a rewrite base issue. If there is this file, remove it and try refreshing. Make sure your `index.php` is being moved as well. Very odd, friend.